# Вывод структуры очереди

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
/*Создать очередь, введя элемент 3.8. Заполнение очереди произвадить 7 числами
 * А[i]=sqrt(i). После окончания ввода в окне вывести структуру очереди. 
 * 
*/
struct X{
    float Value;
    X *p;
};

X*FirstElement(float A)
{
    X *FirstX;
    FirstX=(X*)malloc(sizeof(X));
    FirstX->Value=A;
    FirstX->p=0;
    return FirstX;
}
void In(X**EndX,float A)
{ //заносит последующие элементы в конец очереди
    X*ElementX;
    ElementX=(X*)malloc(sizeof(X));
    ElementX->Value=sqrt(A);
    ElementX->p=0;
    (*EndX)->p=ElementX;  //указатель на конец очереди
    *EndX=ElementX;
}
double Out(X**BeginX)
{
    int n=(*BeginX)->Value;
    X*ElementX=*BeginX;
    *BeginX=(*BeginX)->p;
    free(ElementX);
    return n;
}
int main()
{
   X*first=FirstElement(3.8);
   X*end=first;
//Тут не могу сделать. нужна помощь.
for(int i=1;i<7;i++)
In(&end,sqrt(3.8));
while(first)
    printf("%lf\n",Out(&first));

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, немного больше информации. Что конкретно не получается и где возникает ошибка или не правильно работает.

Comment: Если вопрос с тегом c++, то и реализовывать надо нормально, а не по-сишному

Comment: Конкретно не получается реализовать вывод последующих элементов. Не могу понять, как правильно организовать вывод структуры очереди. Так-же округление не правильно работает. Нужно, чтобы выводил с точностью до 3-х знаков, а он выводит в формате: 1.0000000.

Comment: printf("%.2f\n", 123.456); для округления

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

struct qitem { 
  struct qitem *next, *prev; 
  int data; 
};

struct queue { 
  struct qitem *first, *last; 
};

struct qitem *add_head (struct queue *q, struct qitem *e) {
  if (e) {
    e->prev = 0;
    if (e->next = q->first)
      q->first->prev = e;
    else
      q->last = e;
    q->first = e;
  }
  return e;
}

struct qitem  *add_tail (struct queue *q, struct qitem *e) {
  if (e) {
    e->next = 0;
    if (e->prev = q->last)
      q->last->next = e;
    else
      q->first = e;
    q->last = e;
  }
  return e;
}

struct qitem *remove (struct queue *q, struct qitem *e) {
  if (e) {
    if (e->next)
      e->next->prev = e->prev;
    else
      q->last = e->prev;
    if (e->prev)
      e->prev->next = e->next;
    else
      q->first = e->next;
  }
  return e;
}

struct qitem *find_max (struct queue *q) {
  struct qitem *cur = q->first, *pmax = cur;

  if (cur) {
    while (cur) {
      if (cur->data > pmax->data) 
    pmax = cur;
      cur = cur->next;
    }
  }

  return pmax;
}

struct qitem *make_item (int n) {
  struct qitem *p = new struct qitem;

  p->data = n;
  return p;
}

void print_list (struct queue *q) {
  cout << "queue " << q->first << " : " << q->last << '\n';
  for (struct qitem *cur = q->first; cur; cur = cur->next)
    cout << cur->data << 
      " [ " << cur <<": next " << cur->next << " prev " << cur->prev <<"]\n";
}

struct queue randlist (int n)
{
  struct queue my_q = {0, 0}; 
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    add_tail(&my_q, make_item((rand() % 100) + 1));

  return my_q;
}

int main() {
  int N;

  cout << "Enter N: ";   cin >> N;

  struct queue my_q = randlist(N);
  print_list(&my_q);

  cout << "---- find max and move it to head ----\n";
  add_head(&my_q, remove(&my_q, find_max(&my_q))); 
  print_list(&my_q);

  cout << "---- free memory (remove all queue items and delete them) ----\n";
  struct qitem *p;
  int n = 0;
  while (p = remove(&my_q, my_q.first)) {
    delete p;
    n++;
  }
  cout << "remove " << n << " items\n";
  print_list(&my_q);

  if (n == N)
    cout << "OK!\n";
  else
    cout << "FAIL...\n";

  return N != n;
}
```